# Problema de operador AND de mysql en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, operador

Tengo esta consulta que funciona perfectamente en MySQL:

```
select maestro from destajosetapas WHERE idetapa = '18' AND iddestajo='15241'
```

Al recojer los resultados PHP me da `NULL`, pero si pongo:

```
select maestro from destajosetapas WHERE idetapa = '18'
```

PHP regresa resultados sin problema. Cabe destacar que mi consulta esta dentro de un `foreach` el cual ya cambié por todos los ciclos disponibles y el problema continúa, esta consulta *igualita* la realizo en otros archivos y php me deja recojer resultados, no comprendo porque al usar el AND no funciona!

Comment: si `idetapa` son enteros no deverian ir en string `' '`

Comment: Puedes mostrar la estructura de la tabla destajosetapas, esto nos serviria a entender el porqué cuando le agregas el and no funciona.

Comment: Deberias de poner todo el codigo en cuestion.